# Watch changes on Singleton Class

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a Singleton class and I want it to reflect its changes to any view.

How can I call the class from a view to be able to watch changes? What is the proper way?

exampleView.Swift

```
struct exampleView: View {
     var status: Bool = PerixViewModel.shared.isAccepted
     var body: some View {
       Text("\(status)")
        }
    }
```

Singleton class;

```
class PerixViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    static let shared = PerixViewModel()
    @Published var isAccepted: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: Your property is published so you can mark it as `@ObservedObject` in SwiftUI or you can subscribe to the publisher that is exposed for `isAccepted` outside of SwiftUI.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
@ObservedObject var status = PerixViewModel.shared
```

then use `status.isAccepted` to get the value.

Comment: Yes this one works and maybe @StateObject would be better for it idk. But is there another and better solution for it? 
Should it be always called as you written?@Paulw11